# Maximum number of Bash arguments != max num cp arguments?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line-arguments

I have recently been copying and moving a large number of files (~400,000). I know that there are limitations on the number of arguments that can be expanded on the Bash command line, so I have been using xargs to limit the numbers produced.

Out of curiosity, I wondered what the maximum number of arguments that I could use was, and I found [this post](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/argument-list-too-long-error-solution/) saying that it was system-dependant, and that I could run this command to find out:

```
$ getconf ARG_MAX
```

To my surprise, the anwser I got back was:

```
2621440
```

Just over **2.6 million**. As I said, the number of files that I am manipulating is much less than this -- around 400k. I definitely need to use the `xargs` method of moving and copying these files, because I tried using a normal `mv * ...` or `cp * ...` and got a 'Argument list too long' error.

So, do the `mv` and `cp` commands have their own fixed limit on the number of arguments that I can use (I couldn't find anything in their man pages), or am I missing something?

Comment: Why do you have to specify each file? Can't you just specify the directory they're in or something like that?

Comment: @Christoffer I'm not just copying a directory from one place to another, I'm copying specific files, renaming bunches of files, moving certain files from one place to another. I have no problem in actually performing these operations. I was just curious as to what the specific limitations of the `cp` and `mv` commands were.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

As Ignacio said, `ARG_MAX` is the maximum length of the *buffer* of arguments passed to `exec()`, not the maximum number of files ([this page](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/argmax/) has a very in-depth explanation). Specifically, it lists `fs/exec.c` as checking the following condition:

```
PAGE_SIZE*MAX_ARG_PAGES-sizeof(void *) / sizeof(void *)
```

And, it seems, you have some additional limitations:

> On a 32-bit Linux, this is **ARGMAX/4-1 (32767)**. This becomes relevant if the average length of arguments is smaller than 4.
>   Since Linux 2.6.23, this function tests if the number exceeds `MAX_ARG_STRINGS` in `<linux/binfmts.h>` (2^32-1 = 4294967296-1). 
>   And as additional limit, one argument must not be longer than `MAX_ARG_STRLEN` (131072).

Answer (score 8):

`ARG_MAX` is the maximum length of the arguments to the `exec(3)` functions. A shell is not required to support passing this length of arguments from its command line.

Comment: But bash does not enforce _any_ limit, says [this](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/argmax/); it just tries the `exec` and passes along an OS error if the argument list is too long.