# Too many arguments to Bash script?

Tags: bash

I have a Bash script to which I am sending 10 arguments.

I'm trying to access the tenth argument, such as `echo $10`.

Instead I get the first argument with a zero appended.

Any thoughts on how I can access the tenth argument?

Comment: Generally if you want to have more then 2-3 arguments it is good to use flag options instead of using some fixed argument positions to make your code more readable and to remember only flags,not exact positions (like ./script -from xxx -to yyy -num zzz ...). There are some ready open-source libraries for this. Most of them uses bash "shift" command to iterate through them, so they don't usually use more then $3 even if they have dozens of arguments.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `${10}` instead of `$10`. You can use this for a seemingly arbitrary number of arguments.  I've tested it up to `${100}` successfully.

Comment: Try this to test: `bash -c "echo \${7854} " $(seq 10 10000)`.

Comment: Don't go looking for the limit: [you'd be busy a long time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185017/maximum-number-of-bash-arguments-max-num-cp-arguments)