# concatenate ordered files using cat on Linux

Tags: linux, shell, concatenation, cat

I have files from 1 to n, which look like the following:

```
sim.o500.1 
sim.o500.2
.
.
.
sim.o500.n
```

Each file contains only one line. Now I want to concatenate them in the order from 1 to `n`.

I tried `cat sim.o500.* > out.dat`. Sadly this does not work if e.g. `n` is larger than 9, because this concatenates then  `sim.o500.1`  followed by `sim.o500.10`and not `sim.o500.1` followed by `sim.o500.2`.

How can I loop through the file names using the numeric order?

Comment: Related: [What's the best way to join files after splitting?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/24630/30580)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `*` expands in a non-numeric-sorted way, you'd better create the sequence yourself with `seq`: this way, `10` will coome after `9`, etc.

```
for id in $(seq $n)
do
   cat sim.o500.$id >> out.dat
done
```

Note I use `seq` so that you are able to use a variable to indicate the length of the sequence. If this value happens to be fixed and known beforehand, you can directly use range expansion writing the `n` value like: `for id in {1..23}`.

Comment: I tried this for ten files, but this only concatenates the first and the tenth file. I used the loop condition `for id in {1,10}`.

Comment: Ops! I mean `for id in {1..10}`. The other one was wrong, sorry.

Comment: Not at all! `{1,10}` is also fine, but just as enumeration of `1` and `10`.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo {1..12}
```

would print

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
```

You can use this Bash's [range expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/brace) feature to your advantage.

```
cat sim.o500.{1..20}
```

would expand to the filenames in numerically sorted order and it is terse (lesser keystrokes).

One caveat is that you may hit the "too many arguments" error if the file count exceeds [the limit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4185017/183120).

Comment: This is nice! I was mentioning range expansion in my answer but didn't think about doing it this way. Simple and nice, +1!

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know it actually, I got this tip from the _Related_ question commented under the question. In a sense, your's is better since it doesn't have the argument limit issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
ls sim.o500.* | sort -t "." -n -k 3,3 | xargs cat > out.dat
```

Explanation:

**ls**

`ls sim.o500.*` will produce a list of file names, matching pattern `sim.o500.*`, and pass it over the pipe to `sort`

**sort**

`sort -t "." -n -k 3,3` will grab all those file names and sort them as numbers (`-n`) in descending order using **3rd** column (`-k 3,3`) and pass it over the pipe to `xargs`.

`-t "."` tells sort to use `.` as a separator, instead of spacing characters, as it does by default. So, having `sim.o500.5` as an example, the first column would be `sim`, the second column: `o500` and the third column: `5`.

**xargs**

`xargs cat > out.dat` will start `cat` and append all lines, received via pipe from `sort` as command arguments. It does something like:

```
execute("cat > out.dat sim.o500.1 sim.o500.2 sim.o500.3 ... sim.o500.n")
```

Comment: This works fine, altough I dont understand it properly.

Comment: @nerdizzle, I've edited my answer in attempt to explain what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

```
> out.dat
for i in `ls -v sim*`
do
echo $i
cat $i >> out.dat
done
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have all the files in a folder try to use this command:

```
cat $(ls -- sim* | sort) >> out.dat
```