# Limit on commands for a ProcessBuilder?

Tags: java, swing, processbuilder, swingworker

is there a limit of commands on a ProcessBuilder?

I have this array of commands:

```
protected String[] cmd = {
    "dism /mount-wim /wimfile:boot.wim /index:2 /mountdir:mount",
    "dism /image:mount /add-driver:\"driver\" /recurse",
    "dism /unmount-wim /mountdir:mount /commit",
    "dism /mount-wim /wimfile:install.wim /index:" + formPanel.getOsIndex() + " /mountdir:mount"
};
```

And this is my ProcessBuilder:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(
                "cmd.exe", "/c", cmd[0] + " && " + cmd[1] + " && " + cmd[2] + " && " + cmd[3] + " && " + cmd[1] + " && " + cmd[2]
);
```

But when I run it it says '&& was unexpected at this time'. When I change the processbuilder to this:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(
                "cmd.exe", "/c", cmd[0] + " && " + cmd[1] + " && " + cmd[2]
);
```

Then it works fine.

So my question is basically just if there's a sort of limit of how many commands a single processbuilder can pass?

Here's the whole segment of my SwingWorker method:

```
@Override
    protected Integer doInBackground() {

        try {
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(
                    "cmd.exe", "/c", cmd[0] + " && " + cmd[1] + " && " + cmd[2] + " && " + cmd[3] + " && " + cmd[1] + " && " + cmd[2]
            );
            pb.directory(new File(formPanel.workspaceDir.toString()));
            pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
            Process p = pb.start();
            String s;
            BufferedReader stdout = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

            while((s = stdout.readLine()) != null && !isCancelled()) {
                publish(s);
                System.err.println(s);
            }
            if(!isCancelled()) {
                status = p.waitFor();
            }
            p.getInputStream().close();
            p.getOutputStream().close();
            p.getErrorStream().close();
            p.destroy();
        } catch(IOException | InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }

        return status;
    }
```

I'm starting to wonder if there's something wrong with the actual code, not the commands.

Comment: I think the limitation is with cmd.exe

Comment: Im not sure why it doesn't work but I would personally create commands = new ArrayList<>(); and then pb.command(commands). And why cmd.exe in the first place? whenever you pb.start(); isn't it enough to run the commands ? also specify the working dir with pb.directory(new File(yourWorkingDir));

Comment: @Krystian_K the commands are cmd.exe specific commands

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10954194/start-cmd-by-using-processbuilder

Answer (score 3):

I think the limit you have to take into account first is **the limit of a command itselft** (then `ProcessBuilder`) which is different if you're on Windows or Unix.

For Windows, according to ["Command prompt (Cmd. exe) command-line string limitation" documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/830473/command-prompt-cmd.-exe-command-line-string-limitation) :

> On computers running Microsoft Windows XP or later, the maximum length
>   of the string that you can use at the command prompt is 8191
>   characters. On computers running Microsoft Windows 2000 or Windows NT
>   4.0, the maximum length of the string that you can use at the command prompt is 2047 characters.
>
> This limitation applies to the command line, individual environment
>   variables (such as the PATH variable) that are inherited by other
>   processes, and all environment variable expansions. If you use Command
>   Prompt to run batch files, this limitation also applies to batch file
>   processing.

For Unix, I suggest you to refer to the following Stackoverflow question which is resolved now :

- [Maximum number of Bash arguments != max num cp arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185017/maximum-number-of-bash-arguments-max-num-cp-arguments)

Also, you should take account of limit size of an array in Java which is described into the following Stackoverflow question :

- [Do Java arrays have a maximum size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038392/do-java-arrays-have-a-maximum-size)

Comment: Not sure this is it. Starting to wonder if it's just something wrong with the whole SwingWorker code, since it did work when I didn't use SwingWorker

Answer (score 0):

I think the whole command that you sent might be too long for cmd.exe as you use the executable there did you considered using Runtime.exec(); or something like this ?

```
    List<String> commands = new ArrayList<>();
    final ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder();

    commands.add("dism /mount-wim /wimfile:boot.wim /index:2 /mountdir:mount");
```

And so on, additionaly im not sure if you can have whitespaces here, or you need to add everything as a seperate command.

```
    builder.command(commands);
    builder.directory(new File(workingDir));

    process = builder.start();
```

Comment: That way it doesn't run it as cmd.exe though?

Comment: Also, does the process execute those commands in the order I added them?

Comment: It does run cmd yes, and it run them in the order that you add them. You may also consider waiting on the process.waitFor(); to execute one command before running another one.

Comment: It doesn't run the commands through cmd for me. This is my code: http://pastebin.com/FKdLCcLi

Comment: try to put as a first command - "CMD" but therefore you will probably need to follow it with /c, start. I have just tried some simple code here and it works wonders.

Comment: Noticed that this will basically just do the exact same like my normal string array :/ I still have to create a command for 'cmd', then a '/c' then the command, after that a '&&' etc etc. So it'll be identical to my previous one