# "Argument list too long" error when passing a find output as arguments

Tags: python, bash, wc

I have some 5 million text files under a directory - all of the same format (nothing special, just plain text files with some integers in each line). I would like to compute the maximum and minimum line count amongst all these files, along with its two filenames (the one for max and another for min).

I started out by trying to write out all the line count like so (and then workout how to find the min and max from this list):

```
wc -l `find /some/data/dir/with/text/files/ -type f` > report.txt
```

but this throws me an error:

> bash: /usr/bin/wc: Argument list too long

Perhaps there is a better way to go about this?

Comment: Note that using `$(find ...)` or `$(ls ...)` in a command line is a bad practice in general -- see [BashPitfalls #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29), and [UsingFind](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind) describing what to do instead.

Comment: ...btw, given that you have millions of files, I'd consider filtering on byte count before running the line counts; unless you're prone to having wild outliers in terms of line length, it'd be a lot more efficient to only scan the 100,000 largest and smallest files (as measured in bytes, which is a constant-time operation to measure rather than one that scales with size) for length in lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [limit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4185165/4375327) to the argument list length. Since you have several millions files passed to wc, the command certainly crossed this line.

Better invoke `find -exec COMMAND` instead:

```
find /some/data/dir/with/text/files/ -type f -exec wc -l {} + > report.txt
```

Here, each found file `find` will be appended to the argument list of the command following `-exec` in place of `{}`. Before the argument length is reached, the command is run and the remaining found files will be processed in a new run of the command the same way, until the whole list is done.

See [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find) of `find` for more details.

---

*Thanks to [Charles Duffy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy) for the improvements of this answer.*

Comment: I can't speak to the downvotes, but I _would_ strongly suggest changing `-exec ... {} \;` to `-exec ... {} +`; as it is, this is wildly inefficient (starting a new copy of `wc` per file, instead of starting a new one only when the argument list would otherwise get too long).

Comment: BTW, while this takes us out of POSIX-compliance into GNUisms, one might also think of switching from `-exec` to `-execdir` (unless the files are organized in lots of small subdirectories); running `wc` in the individual directories means the directory names don't need to be passed on the command line, increasing the number of individual files that can be passed to each copy of `wc`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Is it a GNUism? `find /some/data/dir/with/text/files/ -type f -print0 | xargs -0 wc -l >report.txt`

Comment: @LéaGris, [apparently not](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/320172/138686). (Adopted in [PASC Interpretation 1003.2 #210](https://collaboration.opengroup.org/external/pasc.org/interpretations/unofficial/db/p1003.2/pasc-1003.2-210.html) in 2001.)