# Problems with interactive kernel in vscode conda environment

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter, conda

I am having problems with using interactive jupyter kernels within vscode when in a conda environment.

I create a new conda environment, activate it and install jupyter. Then try Ctrl+Shift+p and "Jupyter: Create interactive window" in command palette. Initially everything works fine. However, later on in a different session I try to activate the environment and open an interactive window. Now I get

`Failed to start the kernel: unhandled error.`

Looking in the log the error is

```
Failed to run command:
    ['<path_to_local>/.local/share/r-miniconda/envs/ner/bin/python', '-m', 'ipykernel_launcher', '-f', '<path_to_local>/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/kernel-20f53f7c-664b-471c-9e29-26e105fefd28.json']
        PATH='<path to r-miniconda>/r-miniconda/envs/ner/bin:<path to r-miniconda>/r-miniconda/envs/ner/bin:<path to r-miniconda>/r-miniconda/envs/ner/bin:<path to r-miniconda>/r-miniconda/envs/ner/bin:<path to r-miniconda>/r-miniconda/envs/ner/bin:<path to r-miniconda>/r-miniconda/envs/ner/bin:<path to r-miniconda>/r-miniconda/envs/ner/bin:<path to r-miniconda>/r-miniconda/envs/ner/bin:<path to r-miniconda>/r-miniconda/envs/ner/bin:<path to r-miniconda>/r-miniconda/envs/ner/bin:<path to r-miniconda>/r-miniconda/envs/ner/bin:<path to r-miniconda>/r-miniconda/envs/ner/bin:<path to r-miniconda>/r-miniconda/envs/ner/bin:<path to r-miniconda>/r-miniconda/envs/ner/bin:<path to r-miniconda>/r-miniconda/envs/ner/bin:<path to r-miniconda>/r-miniconda/envs/ner/bin:<path to r-miniconda>/r-miniconda/envs/ner/bin:<path to r-miniconda>/r-miniconda/envs/ner/bin:<path to r-miniconda>/r-miniconda/envs/ner/bin:<path to r-miniconda>/r-miniconda/envs/ner/bin:<path to r-miniconda>/r-miniconda/envs/ner/bin:<path to r-miniconda>/r-miniconda/envs/ner/bin:<path to r-miniconda>/r-miniconda/envs/ner/bin:<path to r-miniconda>/r-miniconda/envs/ner/bin:<path to r-miniconda>/r-miniconda/envs/ner/bin:<path to r-miniconda>/r-miniconda/envs/ner/bin:/opt/code-server/lib/vscode/bin/remote-cli:/<path_to_local>/.local/bin:/<bin_path>/bin:/usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux:/<path_to_local>/.local/share/r-miniconda/envs/ner/bin:/<path_to_local>/.local/share/r-miniconda/condabin:/<path_to_local>/.local/bin:/<bin_path>/bin:/usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux:/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin:/usr/lib64/ccache:/opt/python/3.9.5/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin'
        with kwargs:
    {'stdin': -1, 'stdout': None, 'stderr': None, 'cwd': '<cwd>', 'start_new_session': True}
```

```
[Errno 7] Argument list too long: '/<path to r-miniconda>/r-miniconda/envs/ner/bin/python'
```

(I replaced some of the explicit paths with stand-ins in < > brackets)

Does anyone know what this means and how I can prevent this from happening? Is it because of too many repeated entries of the miniconda path in the PATH environment variable? If so why has that happened and how do I stop it?

Answer (score 0):

> Argument list too long

There is [a limit to the argument list length](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4185165/18359438).

You can try reducing the number of conda environments in system environment variables, or create a separate conda environment in a new system for comparison.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What I don't understand is that "echo $PATH" does not give the long path like the one printed in the error message. So I'm not sure at what stage all the extra environments are added to the path, and therefore not sure at what stage/how to remove them.