# awk to count accumulate lines counts with files with spaces

Tags: awk, makefile

I use this find/wc/awk to identify code files sizes with a final sum:

```
$ cat Makefile 
qa:
    @find ./ -type f -name '*.py' -exec  \
        wc -l "{}" \; | sort -n| awk     \
        '{printf "%4s %s\n", $$1, $$2}{s+=$$0}END{print s}'
    @echo ''

$
```

If there is no space in the filenames it works well:

```
 $ make qa | tail
 545 ./vendored/version.py
 550 ./types.py
 567 ./interchange/from_dataframe.py
 702 ./compute.py
 716 ./vendored/docscrape.py
1003 ./dataset.py
1267 ./pandas_compat.py
3686 ./parquet/core.py
14347
```

In case one of the files have a space in name it does not work any more

```
$ mv parquet/core.py "parquet/co  re.py"
$ ls -la parquet/co*py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 luis luis 139281 juil. 19 20:30 'parquet/co  re.py'
(data) luis@spinoza:/tmp/pyarrow$ make qa | tail
 545 ./vendored/version.py
 550 ./types.py
 567 ./interchange/from_dataframe.py
 702 ./compute.py
 716 ./vendored/docscrape.py
1003 ./dataset.py
1267 ./pandas_compat.py
3686 ./parquet/co                   <== Pb !
14347
$
```

I try to protect with " the $$1, e.g. "$$1" with no success

Comment: it would help if you provided the complete set of input being fed to `awk` so that we can run/verify an `awk` solution in our own env (and generate the same output you're seeing)

Comment: FWIW, `awk` isn't needed here. `wc` can do this on its own: `find ./ -type f -name '*.py' -exec wc -l {} + `

Comment: You can't reliably use `wc` like that since `find` isn't guaranteed to only call it once for all files together, it might call `wc` multiple times for different groups of files it finds.

Answer (score 3):

Change this:

```
printf "%4s %s\n", $$1, $$2
```

to this:

```
size=$$1; name=$$0; sub(/^[[:space:]]*[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+/,"",name); printf "%4s %s\n", size, name
```

That'll work as long as your file names don't contain newlines. If they can then you need a different solution starting with the `find`.

Answer (score 3):

Provided that the number of files is only around one hundred thousand<sup>*</sup>, there's no need to use `awk`. `wc` can compute the sum on its own:

```
find ./ -type f -name '*.py' -print0 | xargs -0 wc -l
```

which will output something like

```
  ...
  545 ./vendored/version.py
  550 ./types.py
  567 ./interchange/from_dataframe.py
  702 ./compute.py
  716 ./vendored/docscrape.py
 1003 ./dataset.py
 1267 ./pandas_compat.py
 3686 ./parquet/core.py
14347 total
```

---

<sup>*</sup>The number of files must be less than the [maximum number of command line arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4185017/11082165) supported in your environment. Check `xargs -r --show-limit` to see what the limits on your system are.

Comment: `find` would call `wc` passing it batches of file names, not necessarily all of the file names at once, and so YMMV with the output - it could have a bunch of partial sums and no final total. As [the man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) says about invocations of `wc` or any iother tool in that context - "the
              total number of invocations of the command will be much
              less than the number of matched files." - it doesn't say the total number of invocations will be 1.

Comment: @EdMorton Good point. I've edited the answer to use `xargs`, which at least states that it will build invocations up to the system limit, and added a comment on how to check the system limits.

Comment: find and xargs work the same way and so have the same caveat. It's not the number of arguments that's the issue, it's the length of the concatenation of the arguments. So they might call `wc` twice given just 2 long file names if they combined exceed ARG_MAX. Personally, I just would never rely on either of them only calling the command once for a task like this.